# How can I get all files in a directory with svelte?

Tags: svelte

I want to show all images in a folder, like:

```
<script>
   let list = /*array of all files in a folder*/;
</script>

{#each list as l}
    <img src={(path_of_l)} alt=""/>
{/each}
```

How can I get that 'list' and paths of its elements?

Comment: That depends on how you run your application. If this runs directly in the browser you first need to ask for permission to access the disk, and the user has to select the directory (also [browser support for this will be limited](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_filesystemdirectoryhandle_getdirectoryhandle)). If you have a desktop application, it depends on what it is running on (e.g. Tauri or Electron).

Comment: If its about images inside your project folder look into https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import

Comment: Right, if the files are static and supposed to be known at build time, you need to get the paths in a way specific to the build system you are using.

Comment: @BobFanger Thank you so much! That is what I wanted exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the images are inside your project folder and you're using ⚡️Vite (or SvelteKit) you can use:
The [Glob Import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import) feature:

```js
const imageModules = import.meta.glob("../../static/*.jpg");

  for (const modulePath in imageModules) {
    imageModules[modulePath]().then(({ default: imageUrl }) => {
      console.log(modulePath, imageUrl);
    });
  }
```